# Mockito mock the constructor based api call invocation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito

I have the following service which has the executeSofortRequest which makes a call to the third party api

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SofortRequestService {

public com.sofort.lib.payment.products.response.PaymentResponse executeSofortRequest(com.sofort.lib.payment.products.request.PaymentRequest sofortRequest,
            ExternalPaymentInfoEntity externalPaymentInfo) {

        com.sofort.lib.payment.products.response.PaymentResponse sofortResponse;

        try {
            sofortResponse = new DefaultSofortLibPayment(customerId, apiKey).sendPaymentRequest(sofortRequest);

        } catch (HttpAuthorizationException e) {
            saveExternalPaymentInfo(externalPaymentInfo, e);
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, SOFORT_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED_WITH_GIVEN_APIKEY, e);

        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            saveExternalPaymentInfo(externalPaymentInfo, e);
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, SOFORT_COMMUNICATION_FAILED, e);
        }
        return sofortResponse;
    }
}
```

Now I have mocked this in my test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SofortRequestServiceTest {
 @Mock
    private ExternalPaymentInfoRepository externalPaymentInfoRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private SofortRequestService sofortRequestService;

@Test
    public void test_executeSofortRequest() throws JsonProcessingException {
    given(new DefaultSofortLibPayment(1234, "test-api-key").sendPaymentRequest(sofortPaymentRequest)).willThrow(HttpAuthorizationException.class);

    //When
    assertThatThrownBy(() -> sofortRequestService.executeSofortRequest(sofortPaymentRequest, externalPaymentInfoEntity))
                .isInstanceOf(HttpAuthorizationException.class);

    //Then
        verify(externalPaymentInfoRepository, times(1))
                .save(ExternalPaymentInfoEntity.builder()
                              .referenceTransaction(paymentRequest.getTransactionId())
                              .customerId(paymentRequest.getPaymentDocument()
                                                  .getCustomer()
                                                  .getCustomerId())
                              .eventType(OUTGOING)
                              .paymentType("sofort checkout")
                              .action(AUTH)
                              .requestData(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(paymentRequest))
                              .success(false)
                              .build());

    }
}
```

My problem is that when the test execute and runs line

given(new DefaultSofortLibPayment(1234, "test-api-key").sendPaymentRequest(sofortPaymentRequest)).willThrow(HttpAuthorizationException.class);
it is running the actual implementation and not the mock and then it fails to exuecute further. 
How can I write an integration test for `executeSofortRequest` method

Comment: you should think about `@Autowire` instead of creating object with `new` keyword `new DefaultSofortLibPayment(1234, "test-api-key")`

Comment: Why not use mock for that?

Comment: You need a way to inject mock somehow - eg extract creation method.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you want, 
but in your situation I would add a package access zero (0) parameter constructor
as a way to support mocking during unit tests.

In this situation,
make sure that the unit test is in the same package as the class it is testing.